# Call a different function based on value of $event

Tags: powershell

This tool has 2 possible options;

1. Reset 1 Access Point
2. Reset ALL Access Points at a site

For the sake of record keeping, I have a function that sends an email alert when either of these events occur.

Reset a single AP:

```
 Function Manage-APReset {
        Write-Verbose "Function start: Manage-APReset"
        Write-Host "Executing access point reset for $apName .."

        IF($controllerName -eq $null) {
            Error-NoCon }
                 else {

                ## Establish connection(s)
                [string]$cUser = "srv-****"
                $cPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "X***********" -AsPlainText -Force
                $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($cUser, $cPassword)

                Write-Host "Establishing SSH connection to Cisco Controller $controllerName"
                New-SSHSession -ComputerName $controllerName -Credential $cred

                $session = Get-SSHSession -Index 0 
                $stream = $session.Session.CreateShellStream("PS-SSH", 0, 0, 0, 0, 100)
                sleep 4
                Write-Host "Connected. Authenticating for SSH Stream.."

                ## Invoke login
                $stream.WriteLine('srv-*****')
                sleep 3
                $stream.WriteLine('X********j8')
                sleep 2
                $Stream.Read() 
                Write-Host "Authenticated!"
                ## Invoke commands
                $stream.WriteLine("config ap reset $apName")
                sleep 2
                $stream.WriteLine('y')
                sleep 3
                $stream.Read() 
                Write-Host "$apName has been reset successfully. Please allow up to 5 minutes to come back up"
                Admin-SendAlert($event = 1)
                Remove-SSHSession -SessionId 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
                Repeat
}
}
```

You'll notice at the end I call `Admin-SendAlert` which handles the email alert. During this time I pass `$event = 1` to allow `Admin-SendAlert` to know what condition is occurring.

```
Function Admin-SendAlert {
        Write-Verbose "Function started: Admin-SendAlert"

        ## Event 1: Single AP Reset Successfully
        if($event = 1) { 
          $eventSub = "Single: $apName has been reset"
          $eventBod = "$apName has been reset successfully by $tech`n Reason Summary: $reasonSum"
        }

        if($event = 2) {
           $eventSub ="Full Store Reset: $Store All APs Reset"
           $eventBod = "The following APs have been reset at Store $Store by user $tech. `n`nAll APs:`n $apArray`n Reason Summary: $reasonSum"
        }
         Send-MailMessage -To "CSOC <blank@email.com>" -From "AP Manager Beta <srv-blank@email.com>" -Subject $eventSub -SmtpServer smtp.email.com -Body $eventBod
    }
```

I don't believe this is how this should be handled as the value of `$event` remains whichever comes first. How should I be doing this?

Comment: `if($event -eq 1)`

Comment: @Matt I've done this so many more times than I want to admit.. that and ```==```.

Comment: Also I would use else if or consider switch. No sense evaluating the value of $event multiple times.

Comment: @Matt what would you recommend in terms of 5-6 possible outcomes?

Comment: `switch` guaranteed at that point

Comment: Looking into switch now. Feel free to leave an answer for acceptance.

Comment: @Matt could you go ahead and leave an answer regarding Switch so I can close this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are using the assignment operator in place of the equality comparator. So `if($event = 1)` should be `if($event -eq 1)`

I see room for improvement as well for you if clauses. You are checking the numerical value of `$event`. It will only be one of those values. Never two. Your if clauses are mutually exclusive yet you attempt to evaluate both `-eq 1` and `-eq 2`. Not the best idea as it make for muddy code. You should be using `if` and `elseif` to contain it in the same block

```
    if($event -eq 1) { 
        # Stuff happens
    } elseif($event -eq 2) {
        # Stuff happens
    } else {
        # Last resort
    }
```

Further to that, if yourself with too many `elseif` clauses, you would be better off using [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6)

```
switch($event){
    1 { 
        # Stuff happens
        break
    }
    2 {
        # Stuff happens
        break
    }
    default {
        # Last resort
    }
}
```

Note: if you don't use `break` it will evaluate all switch conditions and execute all that match.